# Cannot start because cygwin1.dll is missing... Goal is no dependencies

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I'm using NetBeans IDE to make a simple application. When I try to run it outside of NetBeans it throws an error asking for cygwin1.dll. How can I make an application that is standalone? I've already had to add a few flags to the linker (-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc) and this has taken away two other dependency errors I was getting. Is there another flag I can use to take this one away? How do you find such knowledge on your own?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make an application that is standalone?

If you're building a Cygwin program you will need the Cygwin dll. Cygwin is not merely some compiler implementation library, [it's an attempt to bring a POSIX environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) to Windows.

I'm not aware of any way to statically link the Cygwin libraries. [Apparently the folk maintaining Cygwin don't know one either](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.static-linking).

One alternative, if you do not need POSIX support, [is MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

> How do you find such knowledge on your own?

In this case I already knew, but I punched "statically link cygwin1.dll" into Google to find an authoritative link.

Comment: Would MingW be a better idea?

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you are porting a *nix program you may need the POSIX support. If not, Mingw is probably the correct way to go. Try and get a more recent Mingw release  though. The standard release stopped at C++11. Not sure which flavour the cool kids recommend right now. I've had success with with mingw-w64.